# Gene Expression Database for Psychological Disorders

Tags: rna-seq, genome

Is there a comprehensive database available online of gene expression across the brain taken from individuals with psychological conditions? Resources like the Allen Institute's Human Brain Map (link here for reference) feature heatmaps of gene expression taken from healthy volunteers, and I'm looking for similar datasets from patients with particular conditions, especially sensory processing disorders such as ASD and ADHD. Any and all data is appreciated!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to the site. To be honest I would suggest you are likely best placed to answer this question, given your expertise demonstrated on other SE sites. NCBI SRA will host the datasets required and their reference number will be given in the associated publications. This is a standard approach to many data sets associated with RNAseq data, i.e. they are exclusively on the established generic repos.